# redhat linux 8 systemd service error 203

Tags: systemd-service

1. Deployed a sample dot net core web api to EC2 instance in /var/www/hello-app folder using the user “ec2-user” in FileZilla
2. The folder contains the required dlls and other dotnet files
3. Installed apache web server on the ec2 instance and started the web server
4. Ran the dotnet service from command line to make sure it works using command below

```
cd /usr/lib64/dotnet
dotnet /var/www/helloapp/WebApi4.dll
```

5. I Created the systemd service for the Dot net web api as follows

```
sudo  vim /etc/systemd/system/kestrel-helloapp.service

[Unit]
Description=Example .NET Web API App 

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/helloapp
ExecStart=/usr/lib64/dotnet /var/www/helloapp/WebApi4.dll
Restart=always
# Restart service after 10 seconds if the dotnet service crashes:
RestartSec=10
KillSignal=SIGINT
SyslogIdentifier=dotnet-example
User=apache
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production 
Environment=ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://localhost:5000

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

```
When I run following commands
```

```
sudo systemctl enable kestrel-helloapp.service
sudo systemctl start kestrel-helloapp.service
sudo systemctl status kestrel-helloapp.service
```

```
I get following error (203/EXEC) for the third command
```

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-81-1 dotnet]$ sudo systemctl status kestrel-helloapp.service
● kestrel-helloapp.service - Example .NET Web API App running on CentOS 7
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/kestrel-helloapp.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2022-01-11 15:40:30 UTC; 6s ago
  Process: 71626 ExecStart=/usr/lib64/dotnet /var/www/helloapp/WebApi4.dll (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
 Main PID: 71626 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Jan 11 15:40:30 ip-172-31-81-1.ec2.internal systemd[1]: kestrel-helloapp.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Jan 11 15:40:30 ip-172-31-81-1.ec2.internal systemd[1]: kestrel-helloapp.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

6. Opened port 5000 using

```
sudo firewall-cmd --add-port=5000/tcp --permanent
```

7. Made apache owner of /var/www folder

```
sudo chown -R apache:apache /var/www
sudo chmod -R 550 /var/www
```

8. 

I looked up the error and possible reasons related to the error, found following.
Check everything I can think of, still the same

```
The error message (code=exited, status=203/EXEC) is often seen when the script itself or its interpreter cannot be executed.

It could have these reasons:
    wrong path to script (e.g. /home/py/ReadPressure2AndPostToMqtt.py)
    script not executable
    no shebang (first line)
    wrong path in shebang (e.g. /bin/python3)
    internal files in your script might be missing access permissions.
    SELinux may be preventing execution of the ExecStart parameter; check /var/log/audit/audit.log for messages of the form: type=AVC msg=audit([...]): avc:  denied  { execute } or in the output of ausearch -ts recent -m avc -i.
    You have the wrong WorkingDirectory parameter
```

Comment: What happens if you disable SELinux using 'sudo setenforce 0'?

Comment: @TexasDex this worked for the same issue I was having as OP. My question, why does this work, and what are the implications of setting this `setenforce` to 0?